# R: How to get a filename list of raster layers in a geodatabase?

Tags: raster, r, esri-geodatabase

In R, how do we get a file list of rasters in a geodatabase folder?

We know the case of vector layers as follow.

```
library(rgdal)
fgdb = "C:/path/to/your/filegeodatabase.gdb"
subset(ogrDrivers(), grepl("GDB", name))
fc_list = ogrListLayers(fgdb)
```

However, for raster layers, if only we know the raster layer name, we can read it by specifying the layer name as follow.

```
library(arcgisbinding)
arc.check_product()
a <- as.raster(arc.raster(arc.open(paste(fgdb,"/rasterlayername", sep=""))))
```

For more effective reading, I want to get the raster layers name list like the vectors layers case. How to do it??

```
RasList <- arc.open(fgdb)@children$RasterDataset
a <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(RasList)){
a[[i]] <- as.raster(arc.raster(arc.open(paste(fgdb,"/",RasList[i], sep=""))))
}
```

Comment: This may have changed but, historically the ESRI filegeodatabase API did not support rasters. This is what GDAL uses so, it is likely that you cannot read rasters stored in this format.

Comment: Yes, currently a ESRI developer provides a reading tool for raster layers in the geodatabase. But, it seems to be nothing to get the layer names list in R ... .

Comment: Oh, I may solve the problem. 
```
RasList <- arc.open(fgdb)@children$RasterDataset
```

Comment: @PavelNedved, you may submit an answer to your own question if you like.

Comment: Please cut your answer from the area reserved for questions, and paste it into the area reserved for answers with some explanation as to why it is the correct answer.