# Load multiple file geodatabase tables into R directly from a FGDB (arcgisbinding package)

Tags: r, file-geodatabase, table

I have a large number of file geodatabase tables that I'd like to load directly into R as data frames. I have upwards of 80 - 100 tables and it would be much more convenient to automate this process.

I've been playing around with the arcgisbinding package in R, specifically the arc.open() and arc.select() functions, and although loading single tables at a time is easy, I'm struggling to write a script that will execute this process for multiple tables at once. Here's my script so far:

```
library(arcgisbinding)
arc.check_product()

# Assign my fgdb to a variable and create a character vector of the fgdb table names.
fgdb <- "D:/WorkingDirectory/ZStatTables.gdb"
TableList <- arc.open(fgdb)@children$Table
```

Following code I found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/335702/r-how-to-get-a-filename-list-of-raster-layers-in-a-geodatabase), I tried to loop through the vector of FGDB table names to load each table into R.

```
a <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(TableList)){
  a[[i]] <- arc.select(arc.open(paste(gdb,"/",TableList[i], sep = "")))
  }
```

This produces a list of all of the tables, but their names have not been assigned to them. Is there a way to assign each table it's correct name? Or an altogether better way to load a lot of FGDB tables into R?

Any ideas, either using the arcgisbinding package or other methods?

Comment: Where are the names stored? In another element of the opened fgdb? Or are they the names of `TableList` such htat `names(TableList)` shows them? In which case `names(a) <- names(TableList)` should do the trick.

Comment: See `?sf::read_sf` - the fgdb folder is the `dsn`, the table is the `layer`, you can get the layers with `st_layers`, and so loop or lapply read_sf() over `sf::st_layers(fgdb)$name`

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman for your comment. When I try your suggestion, 'names(TableList)', the output is 'NULL'. 'TableList' is a character object that contains all of the table names as strings. Is there a way to assign these strings to their corresponding table like you suggested?

Comment: `names(a) <- TableList` should work.

Comment: Yes perfect, so simple. Thank you @Spacedman.

Comment: Thank you @mdsumner as well for your comment. I didn't have success with your suggestion, but my R skills are rusty so that's probably on me.

Comment: it'll work one way or another, if `st_layers(fgdb)` as you have above doesn't work then let us know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `$Table` element of the children is a vector of the names:

```
TableList <- arc.open(fgdb)@children$Table
```

so that it prints something like this:

```
> TableList
[1] "first"     "second"    "third-000"
```

then you can probably loop over these names and create the named list directly:

```
a <- NULL
for(T_name in TableList){
   a[[T_name]] <- arc.select(
          arc.open(
             paste(gdb,"/",T_name, sep = "")
           )
       )
 }
```

If that doesn't work then your original code followed by:

```
 names(a) <- TableList
```

should.